# include bootstrap to index from node modules

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to learn some front end from the basics. What I have done is set up my `node`, installed `npm`.

`npm init` to create my package.json file where I can add all my dependencies.

First thing I installed was bootstrap like so: `npm install bootstrap@3 --save`. This created a `node_modules` directory and within it bootstrap directory.

But I cannot figure out how I can include my bootstrap into `index.html`
What is the best way to actually include bootstrap? Is there an automated way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

If you npm install bootstrap (if you dont use a particular grunt or gulp file to move to a dist folder), your bootstrap will be located in "./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" if I m not wrong. So you will have to link it from there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Or you could put a static folder in middleware, then link it in html file like this:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
```

then add the link like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not working for me, the '/js' part doesn't work, if I put it like '' and then the rest it would, any idea why?