# How could I possibly include or import bootstrap installed with npm and all its dependencies from the node modules in to my node-express application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-modules, popper.js

I am building a node and express application, I installed all the dependences including bootstrap jquery and popper.js with npm. Now I have a challenge of how I could really include or import all these dependences to be in use in my project

Comment: I learned by doing something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839062/include-bootstrap-to-index-from-node-modules --- but what people do nowadays is `import boostrap` in something like vue / react https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037657/how-to-include-bootstrap-css-and-js-in-reactjs-app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.